# Dali thermal DLC384 datasheet

Tags: datasheet, infrared, pinout

I have ordered this chip DLC384 from Dali-thermal some time ago but unfortunately never received the electric pin-outs and usage description/interface description.

I mailed them multiple times over the years and never got a reply. I tried everything.

Can someone who has access to this data please share a copy with me? I am open to sign NDA if required. But it should be a pretty standard interface... Just need to know the voltage levels and pin outs. I just want to be able to do something with this chip for private projects. It wasn't cheap.

Comment: I tried again, this time I wrote support in Chinese and it worked, they provided everything I needed.